# export more than one pdf at the same time jasper report jsf2

Tags: http, servlets, jsf-2, download, httpresponse

is there any way to export a lot of pdf at the same time, with jasper report and jsf2

here is the code which I use to export one pdf  :

```
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachement; filename=" + nom + ".pdf");
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,servletOutputStream);
    //servletOutputStream.close();
    //servletOutputStream.flush();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

but to export two at the same time, I collected them in this :

```
List<JasperPrint> jprintlist = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
     jprintlist.add(jasperPrint_1);
     jprintlist.add(jasperPrint_2);
```

but I don't know how to export them

do you have any idea

thank you in advance

Comment: IMHO you should not ask for jasper/pdf/primefaces; what you are asking for is "multiple HTTP file content downloads", may use tags servlet, http, jsf. - nice topic anyway, regards.

Comment: Zip em and ship em. HTTP by definition is a single request/response mechanism. No way (that I'm aware of) to return multiple responses for a single request. Standard practice is to bundle the files into a zip file and send that one zip file in the response

Comment: then, no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

you can use: 
*exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jprintlist);*
for export a list of files.

link: [How to insert two pages in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164089/how-to-insert-two-pages-in-report)